# Flask how to implement a User self-remove function

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a flask web app. User need to have a self-removal function. Basically to delete himself in the database. I have no idea how to implement this. I saw flask-security has delete_user. But don't know to to use it.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

That's my user model. UserMix is from flask-login Anyone can help out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it myself. Here is my solution:

In User model

```
def remove(self):
    db.session.delete(self)
```

In views

```
@main.route('/remove', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def remove():
    current_user.remove()
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are no longer exist')
    return redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that accepts username in parameter

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # Declarations here
    def delete(username):
        db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).delete()
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: it's a self delete. Suppose not to pass username cause it can delete other accounts.